# Mock patches don't work more than once

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I cannot get mock's patches to work. In the following code, only the first `assertEqual` inside `test_base` succeeds. If I swap the first with the second, again only the first one succeeds.

```
import os
import mock

def fake_isfile(filename):
    if filename == 'file.py':
        return True
    return False


def fake_walk():
    yield '.', ['tests', 'sub', '.hid'], ['tox.ini', 'amod.py', 'test_all.py']
    yield './tests', [], ['test_amod.py', 'run.py', '.hid.py']
    yield './sub', [], ['amod.py', 'bmod.py']


class TestIterFilenames(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.iter_files = lambda *a, **kw: list(tools.iter_filenames(*a, **kw))

    def test_stdin(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.iter_files(['-']), ['-'])

    @mock.patch('tools.os.path')
    @mock.patch('tools.os')
    def test_all(self, os_mod, os_path_mod):
        os_path_mod.normpath = os.path.normpath
        os_path_mod.basename = os.path.basename
        os_path_mod.join = os.path.join
        os_path_mod.isfile.side_effect = fake_isfile
        os_mod.walk.return_value = fake_walk()

        self.assertEqual(self.iter_files(['file.py', 'random/path']),
                         ['file.py', 'amod.py', 'test_all.py',
                          'tests/test_amod.py', 'tests/run.py', 'sub/amod.py',
                          'sub/bmod.py'])

        self.assertEqual(self.iter_files(['file.py', 'random/path'],
                                         'test_.*'),
                         ['file.py', 'amod.py', 'tests/test_amod.py',
                          'tests/run.py', 'sub/amod.py', 'sub/bmod.py'])
```

I looked into the documentation, and I found that to cleanup after every test method I had to do the following:

```
import os
import mock

def fake_isfile(filename):
    if filename == 'file.py':
        return True
    return False


def fake_walk():
    yield '.', ['tests', 'sub', '.hid'], ['tox.ini', 'amod.py', 'test_all.py']
    yield './tests', [], ['test_amod.py', 'run.py', '.hid.py']
    yield './sub', [], ['amod.py', 'bmod.py']


class TestIterFilenames(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.iter_files = lambda *a, **kw: list(tools.iter_filenames(*a, **kw))

        self.patcher1 = mock.patch('radon.cli.tools.os.path')
        self.patcher2 = mock.patch('radon.cli.tools.os')

        os_path_mod = self.patcher1.start()
        os_mod = self.patcher2.start()
        os_path_mod.normpath = os.path.normpath
        os_path_mod.basename = os.path.basename
        os_path_mod.join = os.path.join
        os_path_mod.isfile.side_effect = fake_isfile
        os_mod.walk.return_value = fake_walk()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patcher1.stop()
        self.patcher2.stop()

    def test_base(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.iter_files(['file.py', 'random/path']),
                         ['file.py', 'amod.py', 'test_all.py',
                          'tests/test_amod.py', 'tests/run.py', 'sub/amod.py',
                          'sub/bmod.py'])

    def test_exclude(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.iter_files(['file.py', 'random/path'],
                                         'test_.*'),
                         ['file.py', 'amod.py', 'tests/test_amod.py',
                          'tests/run.py', 'sub/amod.py', 'sub/bmod.py'])
```

However, even in this case the second test method fails because `fake_walk` **does not get called** (I am sure of this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fake_walk` is a generator, and as such it can only be iterated over *once*. Use it as a `side_effect` instead so it is called anew each time `os.walk()` is called:

```
os_mod.walk.side_effect = fake_walk
```

Since you are not actually testing if `os.walk()` is called, you may as well just set the whole attribute to the function:

```
os_mod.walk = fake_walk
```